# Should I duplicate previous scenes?

Tags: workflow

I am making a short film with multiple scenes, and I was wondering if I should keep my previous scene and just duplicate it, or move on and continue editing the same scene. Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible workflows for this that depend on your needs.  Here is mine:

- Create one file for each model used in any scene.
- Create one scene file for every different collection of models.  *Link* the models into this scene file.
- Create one shot file for every shot.
  *Link* the relevant scene into the shot file.
  *Link* models that aren't changed for that scene.
  *Append* models that are modified for the scene.

Link models if edits to them should appear in all shots.  This avoids having to find the model in each shot file and repeating the edit.  For example, you decide to make a statue taller everywhere it appears.

Append models if edits to them are meant to differ from scene to scene. For example, you have a prop that has a different color in some scenes.

This will save you much work and confusion as your conception of the appearance of shots changes.

I made my first short following the workflow using
[image: book]
I do recommend the book.